# Убрать дубликаты в строке URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

На сайте есть правило преобразования в ЧПУ URL:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule /?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Возникла проблема с дубликатами в строке url: `example.com/page/page/page/...`
Тем же способом можно наплодить дубликатов в get: `example.com/?id=page&id=page&id=page...`

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способы избавления от дубликатов как в строке с ЧПУ URL, так и в GET запросах?